# Android parsing XML data example, webView or listView?

Tags: android, html, webview, xml-parsing

I'm following [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) tutorial and I modified the example code to let it work for my XML file, now it renders HTML into a webView and the result is a raw list of items (not very beautiful). I don't understand why it chose a webView to display data. Now I don't know how to go forward, should I follow the original approach adding CSS styles and HTML or should I get data and display them with a native listView? my problem is that the whole example is build on the HTML string composition and it seems quite difficult to modify to get only data and put in a listview.

Comment: If you render an xml file in a WebView, you don't even need to parse it. Use an xsl file to transform it into a nice html automatically...

Comment: I have some controls to implement. My XML is a podcast, so I need audio controls and I would like to open a player each time I click on an item.

Comment: Then, the ListView approach seems to me the best way to go.